# How to create append multiple charts to a d3 unordered list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to add a React.js chart to an unordered list that I create with d3.

I am passing in a list of data points and for each one of those, I want to trigger the call to add and display a new chart as part of the that unordered list.  Right now, the best I can do is get a single chart to display (although the code below causes an error).  I want it to display multiple charts, although in this case the charts below will all be the same.  (Getting different charts will be the next step after this is solved.)

The code below works by first calling the display_charts function which clears any existing unordered lists, then it adds list items for each point in the data set.

How do I change this to correctly display multiple charts?

Thanks in advance!

```
function display_chart(_err, _responseObjectFromRequestCall) {
    var targetElement = document.getElementById('chart');
    try {
        var responseText = _responseObjectFromRequestCall.responseText
        responseText = responseText.replace("dataSource", "//rrag.github.io/react-stockcharts/data/MSFT.tsv")
        var transformedResponse = Babel.transform(responseText, { presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-3"] }).code;
        eval(transformedResponse)
        ;
    } catch (error) {
        targetElement.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + error.message
        ;
    }        
}

function display_charts(_data) {

    node_notes.selectAll("ul").remove() // remove any existing list
    var list = node_notes.append("ul")
        // .selectAll("ul") // add a new unordered list
        // .data( _data)
        // .enter()
        // .append("ul")
        ;

    var listItems = list
        .selectAll("li") // select all list items
        .data( _data, function(_datum) {
            d3.request("chart.jsx").get(display_stock_chart)
            ;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("li") // select add a list item

}
```

Comment: Why should you use babel transform? can you just do something like
`<li><Chart1 /></li><li><Chart2 /></li>`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I hate to say it, I don't really understand the question.  Your library uses react which I am just learning, and your example also use Babel, which I am also learning.  It seems like I'd like to do what you are suggesting but I'm not sure how to

Comment: I understand it can be overwhelming, it would be good to create a few different components say `Chart1.js`, `Chart2.js` ... each of which export a very simple react component, something as simple as `export default function Chart1() { return <div /> }` and then import these 2 into another .js file. Once you get that part working you can change `Chart1.js` to add your chart. I suggest spending sometime creating a simpler react app before jumping into react-stockcharts